# How can I add my controllers and views in a plugin for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I am trying to make a test plugin . Although I am able to add methods to activerecord from my plugin , but I am not able to define a controller and view in my plugin .
I thought , I would just inherit from ActionController::Base and then define a route and it would reach my plugin but that does not seems to work .

Do I need to do anything special to have requests come to the controller class written in my plugin and be able to render views with javascript etc from my plugin itself ?

I see that there are a lot of plugin like newrelic etc that do this , so it should be possible . I tried to explore newrelics , but it seems to a lot of thing and is quite complicated .

Please advise .

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with rails engines. There is a railscast about this topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines